# How to run an external program using nasm under linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'd like to know how to execute a program through code written in nasm under linux. To clarify, I want to run gzip via my assembly code and have it compress and/or decompress an arbitrary file. I'd appreciate any help and/or pointers. Thanks.

Comment: sys_execve (11) will do it. If you need to return to your program after gzip finishes, you'll have to sys_fork (2) first.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for taking the time to answer; I do believe that you've nudged me in the right direction! I'm grateful.